# Passing paramater values in Mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to pass a Mongoose query as a parameter to another function. For some reason, the variables I send as part of the query are not passed along. This is my code:

```
get: function(req, res) {
  var my_query = {name: {$regex: req.body.name, $options: 'i'}};
  user.find(my_query, function(err, users) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({err});
    else return res.status(200).json({users});
  });
}
```

`user.js:`

```
find: function(my_query, next) {
  User.find(my_query).exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(my_query); // prints { name: { '$regex': NaN, '$options': 'i' } }
    if (err) return next(err, null);
    else return next(null, users);
  });
}
```

I get an empty array when I run this code. When I replace the query in the `user.js` module with: `{ name: { '$regex': NaN, '$options': 'i' } }`, it works just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: @nem035 Yeah sorry, I was trying something and forgot to remove it. Fixed the typo now.

Comment: As far as your problem, you're saying that `User.find({ name: { '$regex': NaN, '$options': 'i' } })` works but  `User.find(my_query)`, where `my_query` is passed in as `{ name: { '$regex': NaN, '$options': 'i' } }` doesn't work?

Comment: @nem035 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

By replacing:
 `{ name: { '$regex': req.body.name, '$options': 'i' } }`

with: `{ name: new RegExp(req.body.name, 'i') }`,

the variable `req.body.name` is passed successfully.